# Can I have two different versions of cakephp into same Git repo? With different Git branches?

Tags: git, cakephp, git-branch

I have a project in CakePHP 1.3 in a GitHub repo.

I want CakePHP 1.3 migrate to 2.x version of CakePHP. Can I work with Git branches?

Will creating a new branch here for CakePHP 2.x work? I mean, alongside the CakePHP 1.3 `master` branch already there?

Answer (score 2):

Yep.

That's for branching is for, working on different things side by side (parallel).
Crate branch for each version you develop.

Answer (score 0):

Create two branches and make sure you use CakePHP as a git submodule or you'll bloat the repository. Then just checkout a different version of the submodule in each branch and you are done.

Another, IMO better way to manage this is composer. Just define the version in your composer.json you want update and commit it.